# How can i detect the real location of the line which cause the memory-Leak C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

i'm having a C++ application which contains memory-leak, althugh i'm using "Leakdiag" and "LDGrapher" but i can't where is the leakage is?!
i'm also using "_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();" function which give me results like this:

```
etected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{657} normal block at 0x00D93B98, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < N   N          > D8 4E D9 00 D8 4E D9 00 00 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
{656} normal block at 0x00D93AF0, 108 bytes long.
 Data: <(        ;  (   > 28 F0 12 00 00 00 00 00 98 3B D9 00 28 F0 12 00 
{655} normal block at 0x00D94ED8, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < ;   ;          > 98 3B D9 00 98 3B D9 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\occcont.cpp(923) : {641} normal block at 0x00D92100, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <            > F6 06 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

How can i know the real loaction for memory leakage?

Comment: What is a real leak? You get the location where the item has been allocated but you never get the location where you have forgotten to release the memory.

Comment: I didn't get the real location of the line which cause the memory-Leak!

Comment: You mean you want to kown the line number where you should have inserted the `delete`?  I doubt that there's a tool which can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the global new and delete operators, and each time you allocate with new, you store the address of the pointer in some container along with the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` information. When you delete something, you remove it from the container. When your application exits, dump the contents of the container. You will then know which allocations you forgot to deallocate. You can use a map container with the memory address as key and file and line information as value.

I think this is as close as you can get to the real location of the memory leak.